# Replace GUID with a new determined GUID

Tags: guid

Is it possible to replace the [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) with a new determined(not randomly chosen) GUID?

suppose my laptop GUID is 95364E55-C820-46A5-8250-92E615E5D06B and I want to change it to 95364E55-C820-46A5-8250-92E615E5D06C, is it possible?

Comment: I don't think that's possible... why'd you want to do that?

Comment: @KhanhNguyen, I want to know is it possible to crack a software which it's security is based on GUID or not.